# Show every self-complementary graph on $4k + 1$ vertices has a vertex of degree $2k$.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am not sure how to show this. I know a self complimentary graph on $4k+1$ vertices will have $\frac{\binom{4k+1}{2}}{2}=4k^2+k$ edges.

I think another way to rephrase the problem is to show that there exists some vertex adjacent to half of the other vertices in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a self-complementary graph on $4k + 1$ vertices.

Note that as $G$ is self-complementary, for each vertex $v$ of degree $d$, there is a vertex $v'$ of degree $4k - d$ such that $v'$ is the copy of $v$ in the complement of $G$ and vice versa.

Note also that as $G$ has an odd number of vertices, there must be some $v$ such that $v' = v$, as otherwise, every $v$ maps to some $v'$, and there are an even number of vertices (this requires the simple fact that $v'' = v$).

But then $d(v) = d(v')$, so $d(v) = 4k - d(v)$, or $d(v) = 2k$, and this is as desired.

Comment: $d' = e$ seems invalid if also $e' = e$. However, that looks to me like it should work with $a' = d$, $d' = a$, $b' = e$, $e' = b$, and $c' = c$.

Comment: I was taking $v \mapsto v'$ to be a function mapping $v \in G$ to $v'$ such that the degree in $G$ of $v$ is the degree in $\bar{G}$ of $v'$, but not necessarily an antiautomorphism. All that really matters is that there's a way of pairing up the vertices by degree.